# Avoid duplication in localization files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, yaml

I am currently working in a project where, for some reason, there are two files for each language that have almost the same content:

```
config/locales/en/my_translations.yml
config/locales/en/my_special_translations.yml
config/locales/pt/my_translations.yml
config/locales/pt/my_special_translations.yml
```

The files with the same name have the same content, translated to different languages. The problem here is that `my_translations` and `my_special_translations` have a really lot of duplicated code. Below I show an example with fake data to show where is the duplication and the differences:

`config/locales/en/my_translations.yml`

```
es:
  animals:
    happy_animals:
      dog: Dog
      cat: Cat
      horse: Horse
    sad_animals:
      cow: Cow
      elephant: Elephant
```

`config/locales/en/my_special_translations.yml`

```
es:
  special_animals:    # This line is different
    happy_animals:
      dog: Dog
      cat: Cat
      horse: Horse
    sad_animals:
      cow: Farm cow   # This line is different
      elephant: Elephant
```

This is just an example, but I have files with hundreds of lines where just a few or them are different. Is there any way to reduce or avoid this duplication between files?

**EDIT**

I am using this code the following way:

```
animals_scope = special? ? 'special_animals' : 'animals'
animals_hash = I18n.translate(animals_scope, locale: current_locale)
animals_hash.keys.each do|animal_key|
  # Stuff
end
```

That is, for each element in the .yml file I am performing some actions

Comment: Why do you need the `special_translations` in the first place? Isn't it possible to handle the special case when using the `I18n.t`? Something like: `<%= t(( cow_spcial? ? 'cow_special' : 'cow'), scope: 'animals') %>`

Comment: I have updated my question, maybe it is more clear now. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [YAML anchors and aliases](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760633) and only override the values that are different:

```
es:
  animals: &ANIMALS
    happy_animals:
      dog: Dog
      cat: Cat
      horse: Horse

    sad_animals:
      cow: Cow
      elephant: Elephant

  special_animals:
    <<: *ANIMALS
    sad_animals:
      cow: Farm cow
```